# how to reload the Table view data when tap on UILabel(UITapGestureRecognizer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to objective c, and i am very interested in learn new technologies.

I have a UITapGestureRecognizer on a label. I am using 2 label ,when i tap on label1 load some data Tableview and when I tap on label 2 i want to change the Tableview.

I didn't find any solution for my requirement. so anyone help me .

suggest me guy's how to change the TableView data when tap on UILabel.

Comment: In a nutshell: ditch labels and use `UIButton`s, implement the actions so that you change the data feeding the tableview first & then call `reloadData()`. You can easily find info on `UITableView`s here or at any decent tutorial website or at YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like following way:

**Way 1:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   ..
   ..
   ..
   // Here is your stuff for cell

   UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40)];
   [lbl1 setText:@"Label"];
   [lbl1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(tapAction:)];
   tap.tag = [NSIndexPath row];
   [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
   [lbl addGestureRecognizer:tap];
   ... 
}

- (void)tapAction:(id)sender {
  switch(((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag) {
     case 0:
          // code for first TableView
          break;
     case 1:
         // code for second TableView

         break;
      ....
     }
}
```

**Way 2:**

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)]; 
tap.tag = [NSIndexPath row];
...
```

Handler method:

```
- (void)tapAction:(id)sender 
{
 switch(((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).tag) 
{
case 0:

NSLog(@"Tap action 1"); 

break; 
case 1:

NSLog(@"tap action 2");

break; 

..... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have setup the datasource/delegate methods for the tableview? Then change necessary things within these methods when the label is tapped and simply call

`[self.tableView reloadData]`

If you don't understand anything about what I'm saying then I advise you to first read some manuals about tableviews before starting asking questions on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

This answer should help clear things up for you nicely and give you a stronger understanding of how to use table view's and buttons to do what you need.

#### FIRST

To [Alladinian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199017/alladinian) comment, I highly recommend switching over to the `UIButton` object instead of using `UILabel` objects. This way your elements can still display your text (as you were with labels) **but** you are able to make use of the built-in target capabilities of the button class.

```
- (void)addTarget:(nullable id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

#### SECOND

Regarding your question, again, simply make use of an already built-in method that is designed for this very situation:

```
- (void)reloadData;
```

This method is available by using / setting `UITableViewDelegate` and the `UITableViewDataSource`. Like such: here is an example of a generic `UIViewController` class that conforms (can use properly) the convenient `UITableView` delegates.

**Header File (SomeClassController.h)**

```
// SomeClassController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SomeClassController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

// do anything here. properties, methods, etc :)
@property (nonatomic, ...) UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

**Implementation File (SomeClassController.m)**

```
// ...
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

}
```

Now by using `UIButton` objects you can set a method that will handle the user touching the screen by performing a method. Like here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    ...

    [someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (void)didTouchButton:(__kindof UIButton *)button {

    // Here you received the users touch event on the button, do what you like!
    // As your question asked how to reload table data, simply add this line
    // after following my other steps.

    [self.tableView reloadData];    // Here the magic is done! 

    // This method will automatically reload the table view to display the 
    // most recently updated data you have given it. 

}
```

Make sure you change your data before reloading, otherwise it may not change both visually **or** content-wise.

Happy coding!